# atop died with exit status 53

Tags: exit-status, atop

I was running `atop`.  It was working, but later it died with exit status 53.

```
$ atop
$ echo $?
53
```

Is this a bug in `atop`?  Or is my system failing?

### Pre-emptive extra details :-)

I checked in the kernel log (`dmesg`).  I found nothing *specifically* alarming, but there were some errors.  See below.

This laptop has been used reliably for months now.  The kernel is not "tainted", therefore there have been no kernel WARN or OOPS messages.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
0
```

```
$ rpm -q atop
atop-2.3.0-10.fc28.x86_64

$ uname -r  # My kernel version
5.1.6-200.fc29.x86_64
```

`dmesg` reminded me that I recently woke the computer from sleep, and I started `atop` before it went to sleep.

`dmesg` also happens shows USB and FAT errors since I lost connection with a poorly-connected USB stick at some point during this.

There were some hardware messages during resume from suspend.  But I have not had any user-visible problem with sleep/wake, in the past several months.

There are also some earlier `dmesg` errors.

---

```
[40654.082396] PM: suspend exit
[40654.205336] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[40654.517627] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[40654.534651] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[40655.519592] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: Detected Hardware Unit Hang:
                 TDH                  <0>
                 TDT                  <10>
                 next_to_use          <10>
                 next_to_clean        <0>
               buffer_info[next_to_clean]:
                 time_stamp           <10267d16b>
                 next_to_watch        <1>
                 jiffies              <10267d740>
                 next_to_watch.status <0>
               MAC Status             <80000>
               PHY Status             <7949>
               PHY 1000BASE-T Status  <0>
               PHY Extended Status    <3000>
               PCI Status             <10>
[40656.239991] Process accounting resumed
[40656.318355] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Down
...
[41013.654127] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 43
[41013.901953] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[41020.270316] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22704) failed
[41020.270322] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22705) failed
[41020.270325] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22706) failed
[41020.270328] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22707) failed
[41020.270331] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22708) failed
[41020.270333] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22709) failed
[41020.270336] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22710) failed
[41020.270339] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22711) failed
[41020.270354] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22704) failed
[41020.270357] FAT-fs (sdb4): Directory bread(block 22705) failed
[41029.558085] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[41029.780057] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[41029.996102] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
[41030.110057] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[41030.332052] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[41030.434046] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[41031.061973] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
[41031.062086] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[41031.266212] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[41031.474101] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 48, error -71
[41031.588100] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[41031.588294] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[41031.794271] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[41032.002095] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 49, error -71
[41032.002202] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[41070.004040] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 50 using xhci_hcd
[41075.638042] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[41075.877302] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=063d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[41075.877309] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[41075.877313] usb 2-1: Product: Nano Pro
[41075.877316] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Imation
[41075.877319] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0703335B0AF92D86
[41075.881530] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[41075.882899] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[41077.004052] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Imation  Nano Pro         PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[41077.005015] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[41078.366583] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15116736 512-byte logical blocks: (7.74 GB/7.21 GiB)
[41078.366732] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[41078.366735] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[41078.366935] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[41078.366939] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[41078.389637]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4
[41078.392305] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Errors from earlier:

```
$ journalctl -o short-monotonic -k -p err
[   14.953318] alan-laptop kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: Failed to enable SMBus PCI device (-16)
[   15.919042] alan-laptop kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[   15.974276] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   19.812805] alan-laptop kernel: db_root: cannot open: /etc/target
[   35.219443] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
...
[19625.693967] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[20606.292276] alan-laptop kernel: ACPI Error: Thread 3649118016 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 2284756800 (20190215/exmutex-382)
[20606.292282] alan-laptop kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20190215/psparse-53>
[20609.491788] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[22006.616549] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[28469.301081] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[28472.604260] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[30297.940165] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[30355.700904] alan-laptop kernel: mmc0: error -110 doing runtime resume
[30355.939525] alan-laptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in `atop`.  When there is a fatal error, it fails to print an error message.  I have [reported the bug](https://github.com/Atoptool/atop/issues/67) to the atop project.

The error was that I happened to run `atop` after I had changed directory (`cd`) into the mounted USB... the mounted USB which I later lost connection with.

```
src/atop$ grep -r 'exit[ ]*[(]' .
...
various.c
577:        exit(13);
590:    exit(exitcode);
...
src/atop$ grep -r '53' .
...
photosyst.c
101:** Revision 1.16  2004/05/06 09:53:31  gerlof
107:** Revision 1.14  2003/07/08 13:53:21  gerlof
305:        cleanstop(53);
...
```

In the function `photosyst()`:

```
    if ( getcwd(origdir, sizeof origdir) == NULL)
    {
        perror("save current dir");
        cleanstop(53);
    }
```

Oh, I see `atop` *tries* to print an error message.  But then I expect `cleanstop()` restores the original screen.  So it wipes out the error message :-).